# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

#### Code:

```
import os
import cv2
folder = ['test images', 'ALB', 'BET', 'DOL', 'LAG', 'NoF', 'OTHER', 
'SHARK', 'YFT' ]
Path = r'D:\ncfm\train'

for i in range(9):
    listing = os.listdir(path+'/'+folder[i])
    folder[i+1] = np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(path+'/'+folder[i]+'/'+file)).flatten()
for file in listing])
```

#### Error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-152-d8f8c2149488> in <module>
      5 
      6 for i in range(9):
----> 7     listing = os.listdir(path+'/'+folder[i])
      8     folder[i+1] = 
np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(path+'/'+folder[i]+'/'+file)).flatten()
      9     for file in listing])

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
'Users\\USER\\Desktop\\ncfmtrain\\YFT\\*.jpg/test images'
```

i have tried to rectify this many times. but the problem still exist. then i tried this code which worked for me.

```
import os
from os import listdir

for i in range(9):
    for fld in folders:
        index = folders.index(fld)
        print('Load folders {} (Index: {})'.format(fld, index))
        path = os.path.join('Users', 'USER' , 'Desktop','ncfm' 'train', fld, '*.jpg')
        L.append(len(path))


    break
```

This is working fine for me. But then comes the following error:

> `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8, 3777]`

I guess these are related.

Answer (score 1):

Use pathlib for filesystem access.

```
from pathlib import Path

jpeg_images = list(Path('D:/ncfm/train').glob('**/*.jpg'))
print(jpeg_images)
np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(str(file))).flatten() for file in jpeg_images])
```

#### Update:

- From this comment by the OP `'Users\\USER\\Desktop\\ncfmtrain\\YFT\*.jpg/test images'`

  - You are not properly using `pathlib`
  - [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)
  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

**Test One File**

- Use the entire path to your file, including the drive letter.

```py
file = Path(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ncfmtrain\YFT\image_name.jpg')
print(cv2.imread(str(file))).flatten())
```

Comment: SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error                  now i am getting an error like this.

Comment: updated the post. may be generator doesnt work wirh opencv. I have converted the generate to a list and also added a print to print all the files. Check if the file names are correct.

Comment: the files are getting printed. But i am getting the same error.

Comment: i think the problem is with this.  ----> 8 np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(file)).flatten() for file in jpeg_images])

Comment: got it it has to be a string.. check the updated answer

Comment: ---> 12     listing = os.listdir(path+'/'+folder[i])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Users\\USER\\Desktop\\ncfmtrain\\YFT\\*.jpg/test images'     still i'm getting this error

Comment: Does the outpu of print(jpeg_images) have this entry 'Users\\USER\\Desktop\\ncfmtrain\\YFT\\*.jpg/test images' ?

Comment: But now i have got some error like ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3058, 3777]
i was using the comand    data,Label = shuffle(A,label,random_state=2)

Comment: may be you should post that a separate question and close this topic.

Comment: here is the link of the question that i have posted. can you please check it. 
    link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155491/valueerror-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-3058-3)